# What to do with polygons that were created from a raster file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.3

I need some suggestions.  I'm working in Arcmap 10.3.  I used a NDVI landsat product to find patches of row crops.  I then extracted these cells and turned them into shapefiles.  I want to measure the edge of these polygons but am a bit concerned about how the raster format will affect the measurement.  As you can see in the photo, I feel like the zig zag shape will give an over estimation of edge length.

Do you think tools like aggregate and smooth polygons might help me?

[image: NDVI landsat polygons over NAIP photo]

Comment: Yes, it should help. Whether it will do enough to meet your needs is another matter. Note that you could have just set the simplify option when you converted from raster to polygon (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm).

Comment: The easiest way to answer your own question here is by testing your hypothesis using each of the tools you mention on a simple test dataset.